# On which site can I ask about cultural phenomenae, online activities/viral trends, etc.?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask the following question, but I can't find a suitable SE site, let alone an answer.

> Is there a phenomenon/name for revoicing a video to give it a completely different story? A bit like "literal video", but devising a different story and script for the film (not a description of it), which is designed to match the video.
>
> I know this happened for "Magic Roundabout" on TV (the English devoiced stories and characters have almost nothing to do with the original French ones, although the video is the same). I can imagine this as a viral trend or something - but is it, and what would I look up to find out?

(The kind of thing I'm imagining - picture the original Star Wars, when Leia confronts Vader... only a revoiced version says "Daddy, I *am* going to marry him, and chasing me across the galaxy won't stop us!" Do such things exist? I'm sure they do but... what do I look up to find out? And what Stack Exchange site do I ask this on!)

Comment: I'd recommend TV Tropes but you might never escape.

Comment: You mean like that scene from *Downfall* that's been re-subtitled or the [Bad Lip Reading](https://www.youtube.com/user/BadLipReading) videos?

Comment: Exactly - like the downfall videos, but not just a "lulz" meme - proper revoice not just subtitles, and a decent size video/film sufficient to have had one story, and be redone as a completely different story. Closer to fanedits than meme.

Answer (score 2):

If your question is about TV/Movie centric tropes, [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) may be a good option.

We regularly discuss TV and Film tropes there and even have a [tag](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trope) for it. The tag description is

> Something recurring across a genre or type of literature, such as the ‘mad scientist’ of horror movies or ‘once upon a time’ as an introduction to fairy tales. Similar to archetype and cliché but not necessarily pejorative.

Now, that being said, this seems to be closely related to non-professional redubbing, so it may not be considered on topic because most of the content on M&TV is professionally produced content. Though, since the starting media **is** professionally made, it's the dubbing that's not... that may be on topic.

Consider asking about it on the M&TV meta first if you are wary.

Comment: Yes, it's a non professional revoice, and that site seems to be for pro content producers (tropes would be on topic but I suspect types of reuse/misuse(!) may not be). That's what led me to ask here. Asking on TV meta sounds a good starting point. I was kind of 90% expecting a site dedicated to cultural phenomenae (not just online ones) to exist,

Comment: +1 was thinking M&TV, too, and to be honest, I feel like at this point they may welcome *anything* that isn't a movie identification / plot explanation question.

Comment: @JasonC Uh...not necessarily. More dubious content isn't necessarily better than other dubious content. Besides that, plot explanation questions are perfectly fine and a largely deal of what the site is *supposed* to answer.

Comment: @ChristianRau Assuming non-dubious content, obviously.